# Basic profile - current position - only one?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

According with the docs : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

we will get only a current position with the basic profile. Is this true? A person can have more than one current position. And the name of the field is 'positionS' What are we going to get with the new API? Only one or n positions?

Answer (score 0):

Only the current singular position is available, unless you are approved by LinkedIn under the "Apply with LinkedIn" use-case to use the `r_fullprofile` member permission, which will give you access to a complete position history.

Comment: ok Justin, but I can have more than one current positions. I can be working at 2 places at the same time. Even with that in mind, your API will only return one of them? in that case, which criteria are you going to apply to decide which one to return?

Thanks